# how to traverse through all parent child data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am making a website which allows users to make connections with each others (something like facebook friend request but for different purpose).

I am using mysql as database.

I have two tables

`main`  : stores username and passwords

`connections` : stores parent and child user

every user can have multiple `child`

I want to make a query which returns all `child` of specific `parent` provided as sp parameter

By all child I mean child including child's child , child's child's child and so on ....

**what I did :**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `generate_child_tree`(in p_parent varchar(15))
BEGIN


DECLARE _next TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _nextlen INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _value TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

set @list := null;
    drop table if exists t;
    drop table if exists child_t;
    create temporary table t (select child from connections where parent = p_parent);
    create temporary table child_t (child_t varchar(15)) ;
    set @list := (select  child from connections where parent = p_parent );
    iterator:
LOOP
  -- exit the loop if the list seems empty or was null;
  -- this extra caution is necessary to avoid an endless loop in the proc.
  IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(@list)) = 0 OR @list IS NULL THEN
      select * from t;
      select * from child_t;
    LEAVE iterator;
  END IF;
 
  -- capture the next value from the list
  SET _next = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@list,',',1);

  -- save the length of the captured value; we will need to remove this
  -- many characters + 1 from the beginning of the string 
  -- before the next iteration
  SET _nextlen = CHAR_LENGTH(_next);

  -- trim the value of leading and trailing spaces, in case of sloppy CSV strings
  SET _value = TRIM(_next);

  -- insert the extracted value into the target table
  INSERT INTO child_t VALUES (_value);

  -- rewrite the original string using the `INSERT()` string function,
  -- args are original string, start position, how many characters to remove, 
  -- and what to "insert" in their place (in this case, we "insert"
  -- an empty string, which removes _nextlen + 1 characters)
  SET @list = INSERT(@list,1,_nextlen + 1,'');
END LOOP;

END
```

**`connection` table's data :**

```
parent  child 
1       c1,c2,c3
c1      c11,c12
c2      c21,c22
```

**sp call :**

```
call generate_child_tree('1');
```

**expected result**

table with rows
c1,c2,c3,c11,c12,c21,c22

**what I am getting**

table with rows
c1,c2,c3

issue I am facing is :
I don't know how can I get child's of c1,c2,c3 and then child of
c11,c12,c21,c22 and so on if they have child.

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: I made an edit ...